# What's the best/easiest way to use Ajax with a Sharepoint 2013 web part?

Tags: ajax, sharepoint-2013

I'm developing a Sharepoint 2013 WebPart. (We're using web parts rather than the new app model because we're leveraging a large amount of existing web parts from an older project).

For my portion, I have some javascript objects I'd like to send back to the server using AJAX, because I'm used to developing with MVC and the Web API and that's what I'm used to. What's the easiest/best way for me to do this?